# How to sort an array of object depending on value of a subfield?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist, lodash

I have an array of objects called posts with a nested field answer. I have different conditions depending on which I need to sort my array.

Example array

```
let posts = [
  {
                        "_id": "610b806ec6386ffa276b6d1c",
                        "post": "CDat the difference between Equity and News channel?",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "613724604dd4b6f39b344b4c",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6113c826a64da80fe48ab543",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6113c740a64da80fe48ab534",
                                "type": "audio",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "611135cf7497d70b6cc2c5e0",
                                "type": "video",
                               
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "611e14329ff0c343540ae10e",
                        "post": "How forex affects investment 6",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "61371b3a9bf14a39207fff8a",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "613719369507fd12f93e3c62",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135f28e29aeae3de45fc8c2",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135f07c831da33c28fc1cf6",
                                "type": "audio",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135eb2d51a8830698d65cf3",
                                "type": "text",
                               
                            },
                           
                        ]
                    }

]
```

What I need to do is...I want to sort all the answers with type "video" to start and after that type "audio" and then type "text" answers like so

```
let posts = [
  {
                        "_id": "610b806ec6386ffa276b6d1c",
                        "post": "CDat the difference between Equity and News channel?",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "613724604dd4b6f39b344b4c",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6113c826a64da80fe48ab543",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6113c740a64da80fe48ab534",
                                "type": "audio",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "611135cf7497d70b6cc2c5e0",
                                "type": "text",
                               
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "611e14329ff0c343540ae10e",
                        "post": "How forex affects investment 6",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "61371b3a9bf14a39207fff8a",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "613719369507fd12f93e3c62",
                                "type": "audio",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135f28e29aeae3de45fc8c2",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135f07c831da33c28fc1cf6",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135eb2d51a8830698d65cf3",
                                "type": "text",
                               
                            },
                           
                        ]
                    }

]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you need to add a custom compare method, check out my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to loop through each entry in your `posts` array and sort the `answers` array inside each entry using a custom function.

The return value of the custom function `(ele1, ele2) => {}` should return a value > 0 if `ele1` should be placed after `ele2`, a value < 0 if `ele1` should be placed before `ele2`, and a value = 0 if they are considered equal.

```js
const getRanking = (ele) => {
    if (ele.type == "video") return 1; 
    if (ele.type == "audio") return 2;
    if (ele.type == "text") return 3;
};

posts = posts.map(post => {
    post.answers.sort((ele1, ele2) => {
        return getRanking(ele1) - getRanking(ele2);
    });
    return post;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use lodash for this. Check out _.orderBy() method. Here is a helpful link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-orderby-method/

Comment: Yes, I saw this function but I was not sure how this works in my case.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom compare function.

This is the simplest solution for your question

```js
let posts = [
  {
                        "_id": "610b806ec6386ffa276b6d1c",
                        "post": "CDat the difference between Equity and News channel?",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "613724604dd4b6f39b344b4c",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6113c826a64da80fe48ab543",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6113c740a64da80fe48ab534",
                                "type": "audio",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "611135cf7497d70b6cc2c5e0",
                                "type": "video",
                               
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "611e14329ff0c343540ae10e",
                        "post": "How forex affects investment 6",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "_id": "61371b3a9bf14a39207fff8a",
                                "type": "video",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "613719369507fd12f93e3c62",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135f28e29aeae3de45fc8c2",
                                "type": "text",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135f07c831da33c28fc1cf6",
                                "type": "audio",
                                
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "6135eb2d51a8830698d65cf3",
                                "type": "text",
                               
                            },
                           
                        ]
                    }

]


function type (t){
   if(t==="video") return 1;
   if(t==="audio") return 2;
   if(t==="text")return 3;
}
function comparotor(a, b){
  

  return type(a.type) - type(b.type)
}

posts.map(ele=>{
  ele.answers.sort(comparotor);
})

console.log(posts);
```

Comment: This only works for 2 cases video and text

Comment: can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result by using JS only by passing the comparator function to `sort` function

```
"video" => "v"
"audio" => "a"
"text"  => "t"
```

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check the first letter in a list of sorted letters(`vat`)

```
posts.map((o) =>o.answers.sort((a, b) => "vat".indexOf(a.type[0]) - "vat".indexOf(b.type[0])))
```

```js
let posts = [
  {
    _id: "610b806ec6386ffa276b6d1c",
    post: "CDat the difference between Equity and News channel?",
    answers: [
      {
        _id: "613724604dd4b6f39b344b4c",
        type: "text",
      },
      {
        _id: "6113c826a64da80fe48ab543",
        type: "video",
      },
      {
        _id: "6113c740a64da80fe48ab534",
        type: "audio",
      },
      {
        _id: "611135cf7497d70b6cc2c5e0",
        type: "video",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "611e14329ff0c343540ae10e",
    post: "How forex affects investment 6",
    answers: [
      {
        _id: "61371b3a9bf14a39207fff8a",
        type: "video",
      },
      {
        _id: "613719369507fd12f93e3c62",
        type: "text",
      },
      {
        _id: "6135f28e29aeae3de45fc8c2",
        type: "text",
      },
      {
        _id: "6135f07c831da33c28fc1cf6",
        type: "audio",
      },
      {
        _id: "6135eb2d51a8830698d65cf3",
        type: "text",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = posts.map((o) =>o.answers.sort((a, b) => "vat".indexOf(a.type[0]) - "vat".indexOf(b.type[0])));
console.log(result);
```